# How do I switch to my team org on the Heroku CLI?

Tags: heroku-cli

When I try to see which apps I have access to nothing shows up:

```
% heroku apps     
You have no apps.
```

However I'm a member of an org:

```
% heroku teams
example-org  member
```

This org has an app.

Is there a way to swich to the `example-org` org on the Heroku CLI?

Answer (score 10):

You will have to set an environment variable `HEROKU_ORGANIZATION` to your team name, for example, if your team name was `backend-team` it would be like.

```
export HEROKU_ORGANIZATION=backend-team
```

This will set `backend-team` as your **default** team.
Now you can run `heroku apps` to access all the apps of that team.

Comment: Works great as of today in 2023.

Comment: worked for me june 2023

Answer (score 3):

It appears this functionality isn't implemented by Heroku yet, but I tried with `heroku domains -a example-app` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can now specify the team name using a `-t` or `--team` command line argument:

```
heroku teams
heroku apps -t your-team-name
```

Full details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/982